# Explanation of Python namespaces

Tags: python, namespaces

I am looking for a good introduction to Python namespaces. I found [this tutorial](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/) to be good, but I'm sure there is more to the story than that.

The Python reference contains information but it's quite hard to read.

Please explain python namespaces. In your explanation please include complete examples that show the various uses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're really not all that complex.  The import mechanisms can be somewhat complex and with relative imports now it can get even a bit more tricky, but as far as actual namespaces and how they're resolved in code, that tutorial seems to be pretty comprehensive.

The [language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) is always kind of the be-all, end-all however, but it's often overkill for those starting out.

If you have any specific questions as to how certain things work, you'll get good responses on here.

Answer (score 4):

It is all tied to naming in Python. Names are attached to objects in such a way that they can be detached and given to a new object. All objects without names are removed from memory (see [here](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)). Names available in your module are implemented as dictionaries and can be displayed using the `__dict__` attribute.

Type in

```
>>> import time  
>>> time.__dict__
```

The result is a dictionary containing the names used in defining objects in the built-in module `time`.