# Do I need to reimport modules in other modules

Tags: python, module

As the title says, do I need to reimport a module in a module that I imported to my main file? Can't find anything on this and not really sure what to search for either. Cause this don't work until I import otherepic in epicness

file1:

```
import epicness
import otherepic

epicness.someother(3)
```

epicness:

```
def someother(x):
    return dosomething(x)
```

otherepic:

```
def dosomething(x):
    return x*4
```

Comment: Yes, **but** if you design your project properly you should not need to. Make it so that classes/files aren't dependent on each other criss-cross, but in an organized tree-like way. You could put `dosomething` in `epicness`. And you can remove `import otherepic` from `file1` in this example.

Comment: Each module has its namespace. Unless you import external symbols into it it won't know about them. See [Explanation of Python namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950402/explanation-of-python-namespaces).

Comment: This was a short example but, I have commands I want in a separate file to not mix commands with code from the program. I use a class in the program with static properties as global dataholder. I have a command which should modify a position and need access to that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to import everything you need in every module. If in `module_a` you use the function `B` defined in `module_b` then you must import `module_b` inside `module_a`, or at least import the `B` function from `module_b`.

Explanation:

In Python modules are objects! When you import a module its code is executed and everything that gets defined there is attached to the module object's `__dict__`:

```
$ echo 'a=1' > testing.py
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import testing
>>> 'a' in testing.__dict__
True
```

The module's `__dict__` contains also the usual global built-ins.
Anything that is defined inside a module uses the module's `__dict__` as global scope.
In python there is no such a thing as a "global variable" meaning a variable accessible from every module/class/function. Globals variables are actually just a module's instant variables.

If you want to import some items from a module into an other module's namespace you can use the `from` syntax:

```
from module_a import functionA, functionB, classA, CONSTANT
```

You can import everything using the `*`:

```
from module_a import *
```

But avoid using the `from ... import *` syntax! You'll get namespacing clashes like in C includes. Only do this if a module states in its documentation that it is *`*`-import safe*.
To make a module *`*`-import safe* you can define the `__all__` global, which should be a sequence of strings representing the identifiers that should be exported when a `*`-import is executed.

For example:

```
#module_a
A = 1
B = 2
__all__ = ['A']

#module_b
from module_a import *
print(A)   #okay
print(B)   #NameError, B was not exported!
```

Comment: It also should be pointed-out that `import`ing a module that has already been imported is a relatively quick operation since they are automatically cached in the [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.modules#sys.modules) dictionary.
`.