# What are Virtual Environments and Directories, why should I use them and how do I implement into my system?

Tags: python

So I have been coding on Python for a few months and I use Windows, I am still a beginner but I like being organized and I have heard of Environments and Directories. I would like to know what they are, why we use them and how we use them.

Comment: I like the explanation here https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: There's also a discussion about namespaces at https://stackoverflow.com/q/4950402/1079354, which is essentially what purpose directories/folders would serve.